# Fill placeholders with dynamic values upon exporting a org document

Tags: org-mode, template

I would like to create an invoice exported from an org document. At the moment I have a clock table which shows the total number of hours I want to bill.

I would like to have a part of the document which is static text, with some dynamic variables in it. Basically placeholders that should get filled with the current values upon export, where I can also do simple math to add the tax for instance.

Dummy code:

```
%subtotal = %number_of_hours * %hourly_rate
%total = %subtotal * 1.19  # add tax

Billing period: %clock_table_first_day - %clock_table_last_day

Units            |  Rate            | Total
%number_of_hours |  %hourly_rate    | %subtotal
...
```

In my document I have many time records:

```
** Some meeting                                                                                                                                                                                     
  :LOGBOOK:                                                                                                                                                                                 
  CLOCK: [2019-02-08 Fr 09:12]--[2019-02-08 Fr 09:33] =>  0:21                                                                                                                              
  :END:
```

I'm barely scratching the surface of Emacs and not sure what is the most appropriate solution. Templating, string expansion etc. I wonder what is the most lightweight way to...

a) e.g. get the total duration of my time records for further calculation

b) fill a static block of plaintext with some dynamic values

For b) Would it be https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html#Capture-templates? Or rather a src block? Dynamic block?

---

Update:

What I've come up with so far:

```
#+name: print-hello
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var data=myclocktable :results value
from string import Template
template="Total hours $total_hours"
template = Template(template)
total_hours = data[2][1].strip("*")
output = template.substitute({"total_hours": total_hours})
return output
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: print-hello
: Total hours 87:38
```

Comment: Have you checked out http://notes.secretsauce.net/notes/2014/10/01_org-mode-for-invoices.html?

Comment: or https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/master/contrib/lisp/org-invoice.el